# Execute javascript code in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just need to execute the below javascript and get the variable values.

```
var u = http://track.fk;
var u2 = g.tv/2grc4?track=pub3878f5a9bae34c50a9f3ab0b59e1022e&pubid=8afa71db&aff_sub=pub3878f5a9bae34c50a9f3ab0b59e1022e;
var link = document.getElementById(click);
setTimeout(function() { link.href = u+u2; }, 333);
setTimeout(function() {
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.httpEquiv = 'refresh';
    meta.content = '1;'+u+u2;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    window.location.href = u+u2;
    window.location.replace(u+u2);
}, 333);
```

I have tried using gem

```
gem "therubyracer"
```

but i am receiving error as

```
V8::Error: Unexpected token : at <eval>:1:14
```

expected output,

```
u = http://track.fk, u2 = g.tv/2grc4... and other values in ruby
```

Comment: Your JS string has incorrect syntax, doesn't it? The string `var u = http://track.fk;` simply just plain text, not Javascript. Perhaps, copy & paste losing some quotes?

Comment: but even after adding single quotes, it says error as 
V8::Error: document is not defined

Comment: I see, so it doesn't about running javascript inside Ruby. You need a scraper that can run a browser inside

Comment: That javascript in intended to run in a browser with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) present. You can do this by running a "virtual" browser like phantomjs but I would try looking for a better simpler way to solve the original issue.

Comment: Have a look at the ruby [heredoc](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ruby+heredoc) syntax. It improves readability a lot when dealing with longer strings, specially if they represent code.